# characters and representations of extra-special $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Consider following examples, from which we observe a property and pose question.

Let $\rho_1,\rho_2$ denote the $2$-dimensional irreducible representations over $\mathbb{C}$ of $D_8$ and $Q_8$ respectively.

The characters $\chi_1,\chi_2$ corresponding to $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are same in some sense. In particular, the character tables of $D_8$ and $Q_8$ is same, in some sense, over $\mathbb{C}$.

But still there is a simple way to distinguish the representations $\rho_1,\rho_2$: think of $\rho_1,\rho_2$ as representations into ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. Then

> $\rho_2$ takes $Q_8$ inside ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ whereas $\rho_1$ doesn't take $D_8$ inside ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Next, what about general extra-special $p$-groups (of same order)?

Here also, the character tables of the two extra-special $p$-groups ($p$ *any* prime) are same, in some sense.

**Q.** Can we distinguish the unique irreducible representation of extra-special $p$-groups, of dimension $>1$, in a way similar to above?

I mean, if $\rho_i:G_i\rightarrow {\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, $i=1,2$, denotes the unique irreducible representation of the extra-special $p$-group $G_i$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with dimension $>1$, and $|G_1|=|G_2|$, then is it true that one group embeds in special linear group, but not the other? What could be easiest way to distinguish representations $\rho_1,\rho_2$?

Comment: I did a quick computer calculation with the extraspecial groups of orders $3^3$ and $5^3$, and their representations of degree $p$ can indeed be distinguished by the determinant map. For the groups of exponent $p$ all determinants are $1$, whereas for the other type there were determinants of order $p$. I expect this can be answered theoretically!

Comment: @Derek: Great. I will try to prove it.

Comment: @Derek: "....for the other type there were determinants of order p..."; here determinant values are certain roots of unity, isn't it? Do you mean, for other, the determinants are $p$-th roots of unity other than $1$?

Comment: I meant multiplicative order $p$ (which is the same as being a $p$-th root of unity other than $1$). I think I can see how to prove this now.